# Displaying arraylist in Microsoft Excel

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, c#-4.0

How can i display  created arraylist in ms excel?
        Please guide me..

Comment: Do you need assistance on how to write some value to an excel file?

Comment: @Marco..ya i created an arraylist but i have to display that arraylist in excel sheet..is it possible?if yes kindly let me know?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a reference to `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel` assembly.
Then try this (just an idea, not full and perfect code):

```
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

Excel.Application excel = new Excel.Application();
Excel.Workbook wb = excel.Workbooks.Open("filename");
Excel.Worksheet sh = wb.Sheets[1]; // or wb.Sheets["name"]
int row = 2;
foreach (string item in array)
{
    sh.Cells[row,col].Value2 = item;
    row++;
}
wb.Save();
wb.Close();
excel.Quit();
```

Comment: I did :) once again Thanks for the answer Marco :)

Comment: @Marco..Now i need to get a window asking me where to save on disk ?

Comment: @Satya: you have to study a little bit, because this is a really basic action!! Anyway, create a `SaveFileDialog` and call it dlgSave and use `if (dlgSave.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK) dlgSave.Filename...`

Comment: Marco but the thing is I want Web application not the windows application?savefileDialog is for win app i guess?

Comment: @Satya: check [this link](http://www.dotnethell.it/forum/messages.aspx?ThreadID=39081): it's in italian, but solutions is there